# How do order of operations go on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

My question looks like this:

```
  10-7//2*3+1
```

I am supposed to solve the equation.

My answer seems to come out as 8 when using PEMDAS:

```
First its's 2*3 = 6; 10-7//6+1
second = 7//6= 1; 10-1+1
Third = 10-8 = 8;
```

But when putting it into python, I get a 2. Why is this so?

It seems the programs order is as such:

```
first: 7//2=3; 10-3*3+1
second: 3*3=9; 10-9+1
third:10-9+1= 2; 2
```

I don't get it.

Comment: You aren't using PEDMAS. Integer division is still division.

Comment: You evaluate it LEFT TO RIGHT so division comes first.

Answer (score 34):

`PEMDAS` is `P`, `E`, `MD`, `AS`; multiplication and division have the *same precedence*, and the same goes for addition and subtraction. When a division operator appears before multiplication, division goes first.

The order Python operators are executed in is governed by the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), and follow the same rules. Operators with higher precedence are executed before those with lower precedence, but operators have *matching* precedence when they are in the same group.

For `10-7//2*3+1`, you have 2 classes of operators, from lowest to higest:

- `+, -`  (correlating with `AS` == *addition and subtraction*)
- `*, @, /, //, %`  (correlating with `MD`, so *multiplication and division*).

So `//` and `*` are executed first; multiplication and division fall in the same *group*, not a set order here (`MD` doesn't mean multiplication comes before division):

```
10 - ((7 // 2) * 3) + 1
```

So `7 // 2` is executed first, followed by the multiplication by 3. You then get the subtraction from ten and adding one at the end.

---

We've glossed over an issue that doesn't affect your particular case, but is very important for writing real Python programs. PEMDAS isn't really about *order* of operations; it doesn't decide what order things are evaluated in. It's really about *argument grouping*. PEMDAS says that `a + b + c * d` is evaluated as `(a + b) + (c * d)`, but it doesn't say whether `a + b` or `c * d` is evaluated first.

In math, it doesn't matter what you evaluate first, as long as you respect the argument grouping. In Python, if you evaluted `b()` and `c()` first in `a() + (b() + c())` just because they're in parentheses, you could get a completely different result, because Python functions can have side effects.

Python expression evaluation mostly works from left to right. For example, in `a() + b() + (c() * d())`, evaluation order goes as follows:

- `a()`
- `b()`
- the first `+`, now that its arguments are ready
- `c()`
- `d()`
- the `*`, now that its arguments are ready
- the second `+`, now that its arguments are ready

This is despite the high precedence of `*` and the parentheses around the multiplication.

Answer (score 20):

PEMDAS is better expressed as

- **P** - Parentheses, then
- **E** - Exponents, then
- **MD** - Multiplication and division, left to right, then
- **AS** - Addition and subtraction, left to right

So in your expression, the division should be done before the multiplication, since it is to the left of the multiplication. After those are done, then do the subtraction then the addition.

Answer (score 6):

> How do order of operations go on Python?

I don't know what a `PE(MD)(AS)` is, but Python order of operations (order of precedence) rules go as the "Operator Precedence" table from the official documentation says they go. :)

Keep in mind, many of these operator precedence rules are *opposite* in Python how they are [in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) or [in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), but [here are the "Operator precedence" rules in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

*To read all the footnotes in the table, click on the link just above.*

[image]

### Reading I Still Need to Do

1. PEMDAS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics

Answer (score 4):

This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (Python Documentation / Expressions / Operator-Precedence):

- Multiplication and division, including integer division, happen on the same precedence level, so the order is determined by the direction in which operands are grouped:
- Evaluation order of all the multiplications and divisions is left to right (like for most binary operations, except exponentiation).

Answer (score 0):

I think that python doesn’t follow PEMDAS or BODMAS, unless you put the parentheses/brackets around it. So basically I’ll have to mentally do it before writing the program