# Calculating GPA with function in Python

Tags: python, function, gpa

Ok so I am trying to make a program where the user has to input a letter grade for a course along with the course credit. There are three courses overall. It adds up all of the grade points for each course (grade point * course credit) and divides by the total amount of credits for the three courses.

So I typed this in for the input variables and it got this all right:

```
Enter your course 1 letter grade: A
Enter your course 1 credit: 3
Grade point for course 1 is: 4.0
Enter your course 2 letter grade: B
Enter your course 2 credit: 2
Grade point for course 2 is: 3.0
Enter your course 3 letter grade: C
Enter your course 3 credit: 4
Grade point for course 3 is: 2.0
```

The overall GPA should be 2.8888888888889, but my program prints out 18.88888888888889. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
def getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade):
  if (courseLetterGrade == "A"):
    return 4.0;
  elif (courseLetterGrade == "A-"):
    return 3.67;
  elif (courseLetterGrade == "B+"):
    return 3.33;
  elif (courseLetterGrade == "B"):
    return 3.0;
  elif (courseLetterGrade == "B-"):
    return 2.67;
  elif (courseLetterGrade == "C+"):
    return 2.33;
  elif (courseLetterGrade == "C"):
    return 2.0;
  elif (courseLetterGrade == "D"):
    return 1.0;
  else:
    return 0.0;
  
# Main area of code - Code that allows the user to input the variables and then calls to the getGradePoint function
def run():  
  courseLetterGrade = str(input("Enter your course 1 letter grade: "))
  courseCredit = float(input("Enter your course 1 credit: "))
  print(f"Grade point for course 1 is {getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade)}.")
  
  courseLetterGrade2 = str(input("Enter your course 2 letter grade: "))
  courseCredit2 = float(input("Enter your course 2 credit: "))
  print(f"Grade point for course 2 is {getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade2)}.") 
  
  courseLetterGrade3 = str(input("Enter your course 3 letter grade: "))
  courseCredit3 = float(input("Enter your course 3 credit: "))
  print(f"Grade point for course 3 is {getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade3)}.")

  GPA = (getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade) * courseCredit) + (getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade2) * courseCredit2) + (getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade3) * courseCredit3) / (courseCredit + courseCredit2 + courseCredit3)

  print(f"Your GPA is: {str(GPA)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  run()
```

Answer (score 4):

Mind your order of operations.

What you're getting is:

```
(4*3) + (3*2) + ((2*4)/(3+2+4)) = 18.88...
```

but what you wanted was

```
((4*3) + (3*2) + (2*4)) / (3+2+4) = 2.88...
```

The division operator `/` has higher precedence than `+` so without any parentheses indicating to do all the addition first *before* dividing, it will do the division first with the last weighted grade, then add the other weighted grades.

More on operator precedence: [6.17. Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

[How do order of operations go on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937457/how-do-order-of-operations-go-on-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this for your calculation

```
GPA = ((getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade) * courseCredit) + (getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade2) * courseCredit2) + (getGradePoint(courseLetterGrade3) * courseCredit3)) / (courseCredit + courseCredit2 + courseCredit3)
```

Following the rule of the Order of Operations PEMDAS. As the `/` was used first without the brackets. .
For reference.
https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html