# What is the Order of evaluation without ()?

Tags: python, math

I don't get why this function returns 2.0.

```
1+1/2*2
```

For order of operations, I thought it would be multiplication first, then division, left to right, so 1+1/4 to 1+.25 or maybe even return 2/4 =0.5...

I am really confused how it outputs 2.0.

Thanks in advance! Currently studying for an exam.

Comment: I'm seeing it reads it as like, 1+1/2 * 2, so 2/2 * 2, or 1*2 which equals 2; so do we not do multiplication first then? I was trying to go off of PEMDAS but I think I probably just over complicated it and should do division first as I encounter it while reading left to right?

Comment: " I thought it would be multiplication first, then division, left to right," multiplication and division have the same precedence, just like in arithmetic

Comment: Don't add *another, unrelated question*. Please take a look at the [help] and [ask]. This isn't your personal tutorial service.

Comment: @statisticalerror try searching for similar question on stackoverflow, which may have answered already. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48937537/14429185

Answer (score 1):

As for the multiplication and division, the order is left to right. So here is the division first.
1 + 1 / 2 * 2 = 1 + 0.5 * 2 = 1 + 1 = 2

For the next problem, I think `if a == 'A' or 'B'` is 2 expressions, `a == 'A'` and `'B'`. I've learned a little about C++, and the 'B' refers 66 in the  ASCII, which is not 0, so the expression 'B' is always true. Maybe in python it will be the same.
So the code should be `if a == 'A' or a == 'B':`

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand it better now. Thanks very much!!

Comment: And if there is no parentheses, do the multiplication and division first, then the addition  and subtraction.

Comment: I think that makes sense. (: Thanks again!!

Comment: "I've learned a little about C++, and the 'B' refers 66 in the ASCII, which is not 0, so the expression 'B' is always true" Python is not C++.

Answer (score 0):

See the stackoverflow post: [How do order of operations go on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937457/how-do-order-of-operations-go-on-python#:%7E:text=5%20Answers&text=PEMDAS%20is%20P%20%2C%20E%20%2C%20MD,before%20multiplication%2C%20division%20goes%20first.)

According to that your math, `1+1/2*2`, is as follows:

```
           /  1  \
ans = 1 + (  ---  )  X 2
           \  2  /

    = 1 + (0.5 X 2)

    = 1 + 1

    = 2
```

Multiplication and division are in the same group and are performed left to right (aggregating the answers from the link I referenced).

Enjoy the ASCII art `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Visualizing it this way (vertically oriented) was very helpful, thank you so much!