# Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'. How exactly it works?

Tags: python, casting

I'm new to Python and I have a question about type casting.
There is my code:

```
a = 5
b = 3
print("a - b = %d" % a - b)
```

The code abobe throws the following error: *Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'*.

If I put parenthesis into my `print()` statement, I don't get any error.

```
a = 5
b = 3
print("a - b = %d" % (a - b))
```

So the question is about how it works exactly. Am I right that in the 1st case `%d` is substituted by `a` in the output string and then there is an attempt to substract `"a - b = 5" - 3`, that is obviously not possible.
But in the second case parenthesis work like in math so Python's interpreter firstly works out the parenthesis `(a - b)` and then substitutes `%d` for 2.

Do I understand that correctly or miss something important?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do order of operations go on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937457/how-do-order-of-operations-go-on-python)

Comment: `print("a - b = %d" % a - b)` tries to substitute `%d` with `a` then subtract `b` from the previously created string. Explanation example: `print("a - b = %d" % a * b)`.

Comment: hi Ilya, you´re right, that´s exactly how it works,

Comment: You already have an answer, but as an aside, I'd encourage you to use fstrings instead. You can write the same with `print(f"a - b = {a - b}")` which is a lot easier to understand, particularly when you get much more complex examples.